# Запуск одно теста с разными конфигурациями на Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, apple, jenkins

Есть написанный тест под ios_app в связке Java + Maven + Junit + Appium.
Нужно заранить этот тест на 4-х девайсах последовательно.

У меня всего есть один mac mini, где крутится Appium Server + Xcode 7.2.1. 
Есть идея создавать новых 4-ре билда с тем же тестом, но устанавливать каждому тесту свои capabilities. Но это будет сильно много этих билдов.

Так как стоит задача тестить iPhone 5s, 6s, 4s, 6 на платфомах 9.2 /8.4 и  iPhone 5, 4 @ 7.2.1. Плюс еще Ipad (3 с разными платформами)
Хотелось бы создать билд который билдил бы iPhone 5s, 6s, 4s, 6 @9.2  и iPhone 5s, 6s, 4s, 6 @8,4 и что бы все тесты шли друг за другом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал с помощью  xml.Запускаю каждый тест с определенной конфигрурацией. 
Как на пример: mvn -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=testIPhoneIPad.xml

Answer (score 3):

Судя по описанию, вам подойдет [Matrix Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin) ([описание](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project)).

Он позволяет шаблонизировать набор шагов сборки многомерной матрицей параметров и прогонять их на всех комбинациях этих параметров.

Comment: Сделал как написано вот сдесь ( https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Yaml+Axis+Plugin#YamlAxisPlugin-2.CreateMulticonfigurationproject) На выходе получил такое ( https://screencloud.net/v/pgr9 ).  Как то быстро все заранилося , хотелось бы видеть сам прогон тестов. Может я что то ни  так сделал( 
@Nofate

Comment: В смысле почитать логи тестов? Попробуйте нажать на одну из ссылок (которые на скриншоте).

Comment: Я предпологал что будет какая то видемость прогона тестов визуально. Он прогнал пишет что все успешно! Как это не достоверные данные как по мне(   Закоментировал строку что бы с фейлить тест. Прогнал через этот билд он сказа что все success. Но на самомо деле тест феловый( как то так